# Bitstrings and flag shifting

Tags: arrays, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitflags

I'm pretty new to bitwise and all the fun jazz and so don't quite understand everything about it. I have two questions.

**A) A flags and bitshift question**

I recently ran across something similar to below

```
if (flags & (1 << 3)) {
    function_A();
}
```

I can see is is an AND operator and a left bit shift, however I am unsure what the flag does and its purpose (to my understanding its a collection of booleans to save space), when I usually come across left shifts, it is something such as 10100101 << 3, which would be 00101000 (I believe), but that does not seem to be the case here. So what exactly are the conditions under which the above function would be called?

**B) Also a flags question (related to the first due to the nature of it).**

TCPs contain packets which consist of 1 bit flags in byte 13.There is a bit of byte 13 (bit 1 i believe) which is the SYN flag to request a connection. To "request a connection" how exactly would you call that bit assuming you can access it assuming its stored in some sort of array and is accessed VIA packetNO[13]. Would it be similar to below?

```
if (packetNO[13] & (1 << 2)) {
}
```

the above checking if a connection has been requested, by shifting a true bit to position 2 (bit 1?)

Please explain these concepts to me and provide examples to assist if possible, I am unsure if I am correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND) operator is such its output is at one only if both operands are at 1.
Hence

```
if(f & 1) { ... }
```

tests is the least significant bit of `f` is set.

If you want to test if another bit is set, there are two ways to do that.

1. use the bitwise shift operator `<<` that will shift its operand by a given amount. For instance, to test if the third bit (or bit #2 counting from lsb) is set, you an use `1<<2`. This will result to a number equal to `000..00100` and by *and*ing, this will check if the corresponding bit is set.

```
if(f & (0x1<<2)) { ... }
```

2. Alternatively, you can use [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers do describe the bit pattern that you want to test.
   The same test can done by using `0x4` as the binary code of 4 is 000..0100

```
if(f & 0x4) { ... }
```

It is up to you to determine which one is more readable.

So, the first test in your question checks if fourth bit of flag (bit #3) is set and the second  one tests if bit #1 of `packect[13]` is set.